# When condition is true in (quotes) then it executed along with after comma statement but it is in false condition actually

Tags: .net, model-view-controller

Ternary operator issue

Ternary operator has to be executed in normal way and after comma satement should not be executed with true condition,actually it has to be executed with only true condition not on false condition(after comma statement).
Condition :
!ValidationForCheckOrLetter("accountnumber", "validateAccountnumber") ? "" : $("#validateAccountnumber").html("required"),requiredflag = true;

'requiredflag = true' should not execute with true ("") condition.

I need this in ternary operator :

```
if (!ValidationForCheckOrLetter("accountnumber", "validateAccountnumber")) {
    "";
 } else {
        $("#validateAccountnumber").html("required");
        requiredflag = true;
 }
```

Comment: Why? What's wrong with `if .. else ...`?

Comment: code readability & has to be do this code in ternary only,
do u hv any idea ?